# How can we choose the appropriate significance level to interpret based on sample sizes?

Tags: econometrics

With the large sample size, I deem that we can somehow interpret the coefficient significant at 10%, but in the small sample size, we normally ignore the 10% significant level. The issue is that, with large sample size, even a hiccup more or less can make a statistical significant difference.

**I am wondering is there any reference or justification about the sample sizes and significance level being noticed?** For example, under 1000 observations we just focus on p-value<0.05, or over 100,000 observations, we can focus on p-value <0.1 (just my example to clarify my question).

Much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please back up your claim "*With the large sample size, we normally somehow interpret the coefficient significant at 10%*" with a reference?

Comment: Thanks @Giskard, I also cannot recall any reference this statement with a reference, so I edited my question more proper